# I want to save it by name i want

Tags: python-3.x

I want to save by name i want

```
name = input("file name?")
copy = input("content?")
file = open(r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\{}.txt", name, 'w', encoding='utf8')
file.write(copy)
file.close
```

I think the problem is "file = open(r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\{}.txt", name, 'w', encoding='utf8')"

please answer or search keyword

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your path construction is faulty. Search for "Python format string". Python has several options to construct strings from other strings, such as:

```
r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\" + name + ".txt"
r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\%s.txt" % name
r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\{}.txt".format(name)
rf"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\{name}.txt"
```

Your third line thus becomes

```
file = open(rf"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\{name}.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Furthermore, when working with file paths, it is preferable to use `os.path` or `pathlib`:

```
import os
file = open(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop", name + ".txt"), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Besides, prefer to use context manager for opening files (i.e., the `with` keyword) to ensure the file is properly closed in every event:

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop", name + ".txt"), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(copy)
```

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) might be worth a look as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fstring (string formatting) to add a specific variable content to your file path:

```
dir_path = r"C:\Users\jikuma\Desktop\"
file = open(f"{dir_path}{name}.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).